# Allow user when registered to browse to username.host.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Asp.net MVC3 and C# and IIS 7.5. I want that once user is registered he can browse my site using username.host.com and this username should be available to me in my query string so I can show the data related to that particular username only. All the logic is the same for all users. I don't want to do any fancy thing like if user1.host.com is entered then I want to redirect to a separate controller and action etc. All the application logic is the same for all users. I just want to change the way the url is shown in the browser.

**Note:** I am not talking about really creating dynamic subdomains. That is a lot of task!

Because routing is so powerful in MVC, I assume that it can be done alone using routing. Also, if possible I want this to work on localhost also in IIS/Cassini.

**Eg:** If I browse to **jaggu.localhost:19883**. It should send me to localhost:19883/Home/index/Jaggu (because by default Home is the controller and index is the method)

I am completely clueless on how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow user when registered to browse to username.host.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442646/allow-user-when-registered-to-browse-to-username-host-com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of ASP.NET MVC routing it's easy. Simply write a custom route:

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    public MyRoute(string url, object defaults)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        var tokens = httpContext.Request.Url.Host.Split('.');
        if (tokens.Length > 1)
        {
            rd.Values["username"] = tokens[0];
        }
        return rd;
    }
}
```

and then register this route:

```
routes.Add(
    "Default",
    new MyRoute(
        "{controller}/{action}/{username}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
    )
);
```

Now when someone requests `http://foo.host.com`, automatically the `Index` action of the `HomeController` will be invoked and passed `username="foo"` parameter.

Then comes the difficult part. The registration and management of subdomains and web server configuration. A topic better suited to be discussed on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Is it not possible without registering subdomains? may be just aliasing or something. Internally they should all point to the same site. Don't know. I just want to know whether subdomain creation is absolutely necessary?

Comment: I am not an expert in the field but I don't see how DNS servers will know about this subdomain and to which IP address to route it without some configuration.

Comment: Ok Thanks Darin. You made a bit clear to me. I have posted to serverfault also. May be some IIS or network guy will be able to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It is significantly easier to work with www.{site}.com/{username} than what you are trying to do.

subdomains are meant to section off separate websites; not content areas.

Even if you get it to work, you will discover more issues like dealing with SSL certs (if you need them) and the browser's always fun "same origin policy."