# Allow user when registered to browse to username.host.com

Tags: iis-7.5, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using Asp.net MVC3 and C# and IIS 7.5. I want that once user is registered he can browse my site using username.host.com and this username should be available to me in my URL so I can show the data related to that particular username only. All the logic is the same for all users. I don't want to do any fancy thing like if user1.host.com is entered then I want to redirect to a separate controller and action etc. All the application logic is the same for all users. I just want to change the way the url is shown in the browser.

Also, if possible I want this to work on localhost also in IIS/Cassini.

Eg: If I browse to jaggu.localhost:19883. It should send me to localhost:19883/Home/index/Jaggu (because by default Home is the controller and index is the method)

I am completely clueless on how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To achieve `/Home/index/Jaggu`, the simplest way is probably to set up your routes so that a user name is the last part of each route (an alternative would be hooking into the routing/linking pipeline using filters somehow). For the *username.host.com* part, you just need to "bind your site" (DNS, IIS etc) to something like **.host.com* as well as *host.com*. But if you're really completely clueless, then perhaps it's too early for an SO question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a star A record, like `*.host.com` that points to your `host.com` site.

On your default page (or elsewhere via something like an IHttpModule) reroute the request to where you want the registered user to land.

Google: **URL Rewriting** for more information.